# Como encontrar a média pelo número de vetores preenchidos?

Tags: php, html5, array

Preciso calcular a média de um vetor, mas considerando apenas aqueles que tiveram os campos preenchidos.

Por exemplo:

HTML:

```
<label for="Cmes222">Valor:</label>
<input type="text" id="Cmes222" name="Tmes222"><br>
<label for="Cmes444">Valor:</label>
<input type="text" id="Cmes444" name="Tmes444"><br>
<label for="Cmes666">Valor:</label>
<input type="text" id="Cmes666" name="Tmes666"><br>
<label for="Cmes888">Valor:</label>
<input type="text" id="Cmes888" name="Tmes888"><br>
```

O PHP:

```
$salbasetar[0] = $_POST ["Tmes222"]; 
$salbasetar[1] = $_POST ["Tmes444"];
$salbasetar[2] = $_POST ["Tmes666"];
$salbasetar[3] = $_POST ["Tmes888"];

$salbasetarm = ($salbasetar[0] + $salbasetar[1] + $salbasetar[2] + $salbasetar[3]) / 4;
```

Então ao invés de 4, quero dividir pelo número de vetores que foram preenchidos. Já pesquisei bastante mas nada serviu. Penso que deve dar pra fazer com `count` ou `foreach`, mas não consegui fazer... alguém poderia dar um exemplo?

Comment: Veja se [esta pergunta](http://stackoverflow.com/q/381265/4056678) o ajuda.

Comment: Esta talvez funcionasse também, mas encontrei uma neste outro tópico do SOen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422889/how-to-count-non-empty-entries-in-php-array Valeu pela dica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei a resposta [nesta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422889/how-to-count-non-empty-entries-in-php-array) do SOen.

Basicamente, o que funcionou foi:

```
$result = count(array_filter($salbasetar));

$salbasetarm = ($salbasetar[0] + $salbasetar[1] + $salbasetar[2] + $salbasetar[3]) / $result;
```